# Audio does not play in Safari, when added to THREE.AudioListener object in function different from where it was created

Tags: three.js, html5-audio

I'm currently working on a Three.JS project that involves adding new audio to a THREE.AudioListener object and playing it, after a mouse click. I realized that this new audio only plays on Safari when it is added to a THREE.AudioListener object that was created within the same function. Here's what I mean:

- Works everywhere:

```
//This is all within the same function, triggered by a mouse click.
const listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
const audio = new THREE.Audio(listener);
const file = <audio file>;
const loader = new THREE.AudioLoader();
loader.load( file, function ( buffer ) {
    audio.setBuffer( buffer );
    audio.play();
    } );
```

- Does not work on Safari:

```
const listener = new THREE.AudioListener();

//Function triggered by a mouse click.
function f(){
        //<listener> is successfully made available within this function
        const audio = new THREE.Audio(listener);
        const file = <audio file>;
        const loader = new THREE.AudioLoader();
        loader.load( file, function ( buffer ) {
            audio.setBuffer( buffer );
            audio.play();
            } );
        };
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. So far the code works on desktop Chrome and Firefox, but not on Safari.
What I'm essentially trying to do, is to play a generated audio file upon every mouse click, using the same THREE.AudioListener object. The audio file changes between mouse clicks.

I'd appreciate explanations for this behaviour on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Safari is very strict when it comes to user activation. I guess that's what is causing the problem.

When you call `new THREE.AudioListener()` it will internally create a new `AudioContext`.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ce0b3d0415c4bc87a8b4ad01c5d21cc26c6ec5eb/src/audio/AudioListener.js#L20

This `AudioContext` will usually be unlocked if it was created in response to a user action. You probably have to unlock it manually if it was created before by calling `resume()` from within your function that gets triggered by the click event.

```js
listener.context.resume();
```